# Designing a secure network layout

Tags: networking, linux-networking, switch, security

Over the last few years I've accumulated a lot of hardware that all currently exists on a flat network. There are a number of devices: my desktop, laptop, and computers of the rest of the people I live with, a development and git server, a backup server, a server running a httpd and mysqld in isolated lxc containers which each have their own routable IPs.

I just recently inherited a (not terrible) managed switch and I'd like to build up a much more secure network layout, I'm not really expected to get attacked but in the near future I'm going to start working on much more complex networks than I am used to and I'd like to get into it a bit myself so I'm not blind-sided.

I'm coming to this from a programmers mindset, since I started playing with linux as a kid I've always worked on a flat network at home, I get subnets and vlans (kinda... less of the latter) and dhcp and stuff, but I never really dived seriously into network structure because the hardware to do that kind of thing was cost-prohibitive.

So here we go, from my very naive network security I tried to put together a diagram of sorts of what I think would work

[image: my (probably bad) layout]

Let me explain why I think this would work and if you can correct my thinking or provide better solutions please do!

I want to separate out all my random non-linux daily machines and those of the people I live with from the rest of my stuff to a degree on a separate vlan, mostly to reduce random conflicts with file sharing and stuff like that and also to reduce the attack surface.

I want to have a second vlan to hold all my linux machines, my git/dev machine, backup server, and the lxc host, which would need to have access to the outside world for package maintenance and backing up servers which I maintain in the outside world, as well as communicate with my first vlan so that my backup server can backup from my desktop/laptop machines and so I can connect to my dev/backup/lxc servers via ssh and http on my dev server to access my gitlab interface.

Then I have the third vlan, this is where things get weird and confusing for me. I have two containers on my lxc host, each of these have their own routable IPs that are currently accessible on my flat network, what I'd like to do is give them static IPs that exist within a vlan that exists on the switch that is separate from the other two. Now I'm slightly confused because it would be kind of a virtual-vlan since it wouldn't actually be assigned to any port on the switch itself (I'm kinda assuming some managed switches do have this feature and I've not just pulled it out of my ass). This vlan only allows http access from outside it's vlan for now since I don't need to ssh into these containers since I can instigate a console through the lxc host and adding ssh will only add another attack surface (in my mind anyway)...

So... does this all make sense? Please feel free to treat me like an idiot, network administration is a brand new topic for me beyond flat networks! Thaaaaanks

**EDIT:** In case you would like to know the switch I have is a TP-LINK TL-SG2216, but I'm kinda more interested in the theoretical network/security side

Answer (score 1):

You havn't actually asked a question, so its difficult to ascertain what you are trying to do.

Your design looks reasonably well throught out, but one thing appears to be wrong (it could be OK, and badly represented, but taken with your comment I think you may not have the concept down well), and that is this -

VLANS are "virtual switches".  They generally don't do firewalling.  Standard practice would be to have each VLAN on its own subnet, and then ensure that different subnets are routed through the gateway.  Firewalling is not done on the switches, rather its done on the gateway/router(s).

Of note - While I believe VLANS do offer some security, this view is not universally held - they are designed for segregation of traffic rather then security, and there are arguments about overflows between VLANS etc which may weaken them.    Thus "best practice" is to additionally run firewalls on each server.

Comment: ahhh! Ok, so I'm basically confusing vlans and subnets in my mind (different ranges beyond the base 0/24 subnet), so what I would be doing is using different ranges of ports to create separate vlans, which would be on different subnets (I believe the switch I have allows you to filter traffic between these vlans which is cool), then assign the lxc containers to another subnet nothing to do with a vlan... Thanks, this cleared a lot up for me!